# how to select radio buttons option while uninstalling in windows

Tags: knife, chef-infra, chef-windows

I want to uninstall a software in windows using chef .While uninstalling ,there are 2 radio buttons , one for modify and other for remove .By default modify is selected , but my requirement is to select remove option.

How to do so .. ?? 
Can anyone help me out in this issue.
I tried doing the below method.

```
windows_package 'Some software' do  
     action :remove  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see on the GUI is not necessarily the "phrase" you need. If you look at [the documentation for `windows_package`](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_windows_package.html), you will see that the action you want is `remove`.

```rb
windows_package 'Whatever' do
  action :remove
end
```

Comment: i tried the above method it dint work . I am unable to fix the issue. But it worked for uninstallation of chrome . We also gave the same name as its in Display name as its in Control panel .For uninstallation does it require "Uninstallstring in registry key information" ..??

Comment: yes,same as is in control panel , and also cross checked the name in registry keys .

Comment: Capitalization and all? Windows packages are case-sensitive.